# use vue.js with chartist.js to create a chart that track balance progress

Tags: vue.js, charts, electron

I'm doing some training to better learn how to use vue.js and electron. I've decided to make a simple app to track the profit/loose of a trading day. I will calculate the difference between the end balance and the start balance of every day with a subtraction operation. After some trouble I'm able to get the result of the operation on the DOM using the `computed` function of vue. What I want to do is to use `chartist.js` to create a simple chart that will track the results after it is calculated. I'm not sure how to proceed, what I want is to have on the chart every end balance with the calculated difference with the previous amount showed. Can anyone help me with an example?

My actual vue.js code

```
let app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    s: '',
    e: '',
},
computed: {
        tot(){
            return Number(this.e) - Number(this.s);
        }
    }
});
```

Sample data:

```
DAY     INIT. BALANCE  FINAL BALANCE
20/03/2020  2,309.99       2,332.25
23/03/2020  2,332.25       2,343.30
24/03/2020  2,343,30       2,424.62 (+81,32€)
25/03/2020  2,424.62       2,519.56 (+94,94€)
26/03/2020  2,519.56       2,544.46 (+24,90€)
27/03/2020  1,346.00
```

Comment: Can you upload some sample trading data?

Comment: For now I have a table in notepad with some data, I can use that for prototype, see the updated quesetion

Answer (score 1):

You just need two convert your data into two arrays, `dates` for your x-axis and `values` for your y-axis.

```
data () {
  return {
    input: [
      ['23/03/2020', '2,309.99', '2,332.25'],
      ['24/03/2020', '2,343,30', '2,424.62'],
      ['25/03/2020', '2,424.62', '2,519.56']
   ],
  }
},
computed: {
   dates () {
       return this.input.map(x=>x[0])
   },
   values () {
       return this.input.map(
         x => parseFloat(x[2].replace(',','')) - 
              parseFloat(x[1].replace(',',''))
       )
   }
}
```

example with vue-chartjs: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/9vz2qukj/6/

Comment: ok, can you include a minimal fiddle to see the example live, I'm not sure about the date day usage?

Comment: it depends on which chart module you are using

Comment: The data are balance amount, a simple line chart is ok